# Print excel file c#

Tags: c#, excel, printing

i've made a program in c# 
In order to print an excel file, he print it fine, but also all grid. But I don't want to see the grid.

I've done this :

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Ok !", "Impression", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
     //PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
     //document.DocumentName = file;
     //document.Print();

            // On déclare l'application
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            // On ouvre un classeur XLS :
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(chemin.Text,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            // On ouvre la première feuille :
            // la numérotation commence à 1 et pas à 0 ici
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

            // Utiliser la Mise en page avec PageSetup
            // Les entêtes de ligne et de colonne sont à répéter sur toutes les pages :
            //ws.PageSetup.PrintTitleColumns = "$A:$B";
            //ws.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$2";
            ws.PageSetup.PrintHeadings = false;
            ws.PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = false;
            ws.PageSetup.PrintGridlines = true;

            // Lancement de l'impression par défaut
            ws.PrintOut(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            // Afficher l’application Excel
            app.Visible = false;

            // Fermer l'application Excel
            wb.Save();
            wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            app.Quit();

            // Réinitialise l'application
            chemin.Text = "Imprimé !";
```

Don't pay attention to comments, I'm french.

Comment: Have you tried `ws.PageSetup.PrintGridlines = false;` instead of `ws.PageSetup.PrintGridlines = true;`?

Comment: Omg ! Thank you it works. I forgot this line...

Comment: I'm going to turn this into an answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting

```
ws.PageSetup.PrintGridlines = false;
```

instead of

```
ws.PageSetup.PrintGridlines = true;
```